# WKWebView Swift - Get Console.log for javascript

Tags: wkwebview, console.log, swift5

Swift version - 4.2 or 5.0

I have WKWebView setup, which loadHTMLString. I am not able to get the console.log error messages that the JS code produce. I want to get this log within the app. Cannot change settings in safari. Thank You.